# javascript for gridview that update cell value from hidden field and checkbox list

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

```js
 function GetSelectedMonth() {
            var ControlRef = document.getElementById('<%= chkMonths.ClientID %>');
            var CheckBoxListArray = ControlRef.getElementsByTagName('input');
            var spanArray = ControlRef.getElementsByTagName('span');
            var checkedValues = '';
            for (var i = 0; i < CheckBoxListArray.length; i++) {
                var checkBoxRef = CheckBoxListArray[i];
                if (checkBoxRef.checked == true) {
                    var labelArray = checkBoxRef.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('label');
                    if (labelArray.length > 0) {
                        if (checkedValues.length > 0) {
                            checkedValues += ', ';
                        }
                        checkedValues += labelArray[0].innerHTML;
                    }
                }
            }
            document.getElementById('<%= lbljsMonths.ClientID %>').innerHTML = checkedValues +" of "+ document.getElementById('<%=hfYear.ClientID%>').value;
            
        };
function jsBankDetails() {
            var bankName = document.getElementById('<%=txtBankName.ClientID %>');
            var chequeNumber = document.getElementById('<%=txtChequeNumber.ClientID %>');
            var chequeDate = document.getElementById('<%=txtChequeDate.ClientID %>');
            var amount = document.getElementById('<%=txtCAmount.ClientID %>');
            document.getElementById('<%=lbljsBankDetails.ClientID %>').innerHTML = bankName.innerHTML + " " + chequeNumber.innerHTML + " " + chequeDate.innerHTML + " " + amount.innerHTML;

        };

        function DisableEnable(ddlId) {
            var controlName = document.getElementById(ddlId.id);
            //var ddlPaymentMode = document.getElementById("<%=ddlPaymentMode.ClientID%>");
            var bankName = document.getElementById("<%=txtBankName.ClientID%>");
            var chequeNumber = document.getElementById("<%=txtChequeNumber.ClientID%>");
            var chequeDate = document.getElementById("<%=txtChequeDate.ClientID%>");
            var amount = document.getElementById("<%=txtCAmount.ClientID%>");
            //var ddlText = ddlPaymentMode.options[ddlPaymentMode.selcetedIndex].innerHTML;

            //if (ddlText == "Select PaymentMode" || ddlText == "Cash")
            if (controlName.value == 0 || controlName.value == 1) {
                bankName.value = "";
                bankName.disabled = true;
                chequeNumber.value = "";
                chequeNumber.disabled = true;
                chequeDate.value = "";
                chequeDate.disabled = true;
                amount.value = "";
                amount.disabled = true;
            }
            else {
                bankName.disabled = false;
                chequeNumber.disabled = false;
                chequeDate.disabled = false;
                amount.disabled = false;
            }
        };

        function printPanel() {
            var panel = document.getElementById('<%=pnlFee.ClientID%>');

            var printWindow = window.open('', '', 'height=550,width=450');
            printWindow.document.write('<html><head><title>MYMANAGE.IN</title>');
            printWindow.document.write('</head><body >');
            printWindow.document.write(panel.innerHTML);
            printWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
            printWindow.document.close();
            setTimeout(function () {
                printWindow.print();
            }, 500);
            return false;
        };
```

```html
<section id="secMonth" runat="server">
            <fieldset>
                <div class="alt two-thirds columns">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblMonth" Text="Months" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </div>
                <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkMonths" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" onclick="GetSelectedMonth();"></asp:CheckBoxList>
            </fieldset>
        </section>

        <section id="secBank" runat="server">
            <fieldset>
                <div class="alt two-thirds columns">
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblPaymentMode" Text="Payment Mode"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPaymentMode" runat="server" onchange="DisableEnable(this);">
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Select PaymentMode" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Cash" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Cheque" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <%--<br />
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkCash" Text="Cash" runat="server" />
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkCheque" Text="Cheque" runat="server" />--%>
                </div>
                <div class="alt two-thirds columns" id="divBankName">
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblBankName" Text="Bank Name"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtBankName" onKeyUp="jsBankDetails();"></asp:TextBox>
                </div>
                <div class="alt two-thirds columns" id="divChequeNumber">
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblChequeNumber" Text="Cheque Number"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtChequeNumber" onKeyUp="jsBankDetails();"></asp:TextBox>
                </div>
                <div class="alt two-thirds columns" id="divChequeDate">
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblChequeDate" Text="Cheque Date"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtChequeDate" ReadOnly="true" onKeyUp="jsBankDetails();"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:CalendarExtender ID="calChequeDate" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtChequeDate"></asp:CalendarExtender>
                </div>
                <div class="alt two-thirds columns" id="div1">
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblCAmount" Text="Cheque Amount"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtCAmount" onKeyUp="jsBankDetails();"></asp:TextBox>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </section>
        <section id="secAnnualFee" runat="server">
            <fieldset>
                <div style="margin-top: 27px">
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </section>

        <section>
            <fieldset>
                <asp:Panel ID="pnlFee" runat="server">
                    <table style="height: 500px; width: 350px;">
                        <tr>
                            <th colspan="3" style="font-size: x-large">
                                <center>
                                <table>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th >Fee Receipt
                                        </th>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                                    </center>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <table style="width: 100%">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td style="float: left;">Date:<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbljsDate"></asp:Label></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan="2">RollNo. & Name:
                                            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbljsName"></asp:Label></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Standard:
                                            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbljsStandard"></asp:Label></td>
                                        <td>Division:
                                            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbljsDivision"></asp:Label></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td rowspan="2" colspan="2">Months:<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbljsMonths"></asp:Label></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th colspan="3">
                                <%--FeeDetails--%>
                                <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvAnnual" CssClass="gvmydatagrid" PagerStyle-CssClass="gvpager" HeaderStyle-CssClass="gvheader" RowStyle-CssClass="gvrows" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="FeeHeadId" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true">
                                    <Columns>
                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Fee Name" ControlStyle-Width="200px">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:HiddenField ID="hfFeeHeadId" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("FeeHeadId") %>' />
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblFeeHeadName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("FeeHeadName") %>'></asp:Label>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Amount" ControlStyle-Width="100px">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="HiddenField2" Value='<%#Eval("FeeDefaultId") %>' />
                                                <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hfAmount" Value='<%#Eval("Amount") %>' />
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtAmount" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Amount") %>' ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                    </Columns>

                                    <HeaderStyle CssClass="gvheader"></HeaderStyle>

                                    <PagerStyle CssClass="gvpager"></PagerStyle>

                                    <RowStyle CssClass="gvrows"></RowStyle>
                                </asp:GridView>
                                <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvCustomFeePay" CssClass="gvmydatagrid" PagerStyle-CssClass="gvpager" HeaderStyle-CssClass="gvheader" RowStyle-CssClass="gvrows" EmptyDataText="No Record" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="FeeHeadId" ShowHeader="false">
                                    <Columns>
                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Fee Name" ControlStyle-Width="200px">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("FeeHeadId") %>' />
                                                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("FeeHeadName") %>'></asp:Label>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Amount" ControlStyle-Width="100px">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="HiddenField2" Value='<%#Eval("FeeDefaultId") %>' />
                                                <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hfAmount" Value='<%#Eval("Amount") %>' />
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtAmount" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Amount") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                        
                                    </Columns>

                                    <HeaderStyle CssClass="gvheader"></HeaderStyle>

                                    <PagerStyle CssClass="gvpager"></PagerStyle>

                                    <RowStyle CssClass="gvrows"></RowStyle>
                                </asp:GridView>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th colspan="3">
                                <%--bank Details--%>
                                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbljsBankDetails"></asp:Label>
                                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbljsTotal" Text="Total" OnClick="javascript:Read();"></asp:Label>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </asp:Panel>
            </fieldset>
        </section>


        <section id="secButton" runat="server">
            <fieldset>
                <div class="alt two-thirds columns" style="margin-top: 12px">
                    <asp:Button ID="btnPayFee" runat="server" Text="Pay Fee" CssClass="btn btn-warning" OnClick="btnPayFee_Click" />
                    <asp:Button ID="btnReset" runat="server" Text="RESET" CssClass="btn btn-warning" />
                    <asp:Button ID="btnPrint" runat="server" Text="Print" CssClass="btn btn-warning" OnClientClick="javascript:return printPanel();"/>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnPrintSave" runat="server" Text="Print & Save" CssClass="btn btn-warning" />
                    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="Label2" Text="Total" OnClientClick="javascript:return Read();"></asp:Button>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </section>
```

GetSelectedMonth() function get name of the month from that i need number of month and from gvVustomFeePay hfAmount multiple by number of months and update txtAmount for selected month from hidden field value. in ddlPaymentMode when cheque is selected put text of bank name,cheque number,date and amount in lbljsBankDetails.

Comment: ok, so what we are supposed to do?

Comment: in gridview i have textbox txtAmount that update when month is selected it update txtAmount= numberOfMonth*hfAmount

Comment: Whats the problem then?

Comment: And why posted this much code? post only relevant code

Comment: i try some code for gridview but that not get the value of gridview.

Comment: code is inerconnected that why i put

Answer (score 0):

If you're using JavaScript for this:  Gridviews are usually drawn as a table so you would have to iterated over the table rows and cells to find your textbox, unless of course you can reliably predict the name the textbox will get when rendered.

Comment: function Read() {
            var oDataGrid = document.getElementById("<%= gvCustomFeePay.ClientID %>")
            var tableRows = oDataGrid.rows;
            var rawDataRows = new Array();
            //somewhere to put the actual data
            for (var i = 0; i < tableRows.length; i++) {
                var thisRow = tableRows[i];
                for (var j = 0; j < thisRow.cells.length; j++) {
                    alert(oDataGrid.rows(i).cells(j).innerHTML);
                } }
            return false;
        }